# Monotone convergence theorem. Pointwise and $\mu$-a.e. versions

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

> **Monotone convergence theorem (pointwise version).** Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space and
> $\{f_n(x)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of measurable functions on
> $X$ such that $0\leq f_1(x)\leq f_2(x)\leq \dots$ for all $x\in X$.
> Let $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ as $n\to \infty$ for all $x\in X$. Then $$\lim
> _{n\to \infty}\int_{X}f_n(x)d\mu=\int_{X}f(x)d\mu.$$
>
> *Remark:* The measurability of $f(x)$ on $X$ follows immediately because $f(x)$ is the pointwise limit of measurable functions on $X$.

I reviewed about 5-6 books on measure theory and noticed that we can slightly change the theorem. More precisely

> **Monotone convergence theorem ($\mu$-a.e. version).** Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space and
> $f(x),f_1(x),f_2(x),\dots$ are measurable functions on $X$ such that
> $0\leq f_1(x)\leq f_2(x)\leq \dots$ a.e. on $X$. Let $f_n(x)\to f(x)$
> as $n\to \infty$ a.e. on $X$. Then $$\lim \limits_{n\to
>  \infty}\int_{X}f_n(x)d\mu=\int_{X}f(x)d\mu.$$

I know the proof of the pointwise version. I am trying to prove the $\mu$-a.e. version.

Let $N_1=\{x\in X: \text{monotonicity of} \ f_n(x) \ \text{fails}\}$ and $N_2=\{x\in X:f_n(x)\nrightarrow f(x)\}$ then $N_1,N_2\in  \mathcal{M}$ with $\mu(N_1)=\mu(N_2)=0.$ Let $N:=N_1\cup N_2$ then $\mu(N)=0$.

Consider the sequence $\varphi_n(x)=f_n(x)\chi_{X\setminus N}(x)$ and $\varphi(x)=f(x)\chi_{X\setminus N} (x)$. We see that $\varphi_n(x), \varphi(x)$ are measurable and $\varphi_1(x)\leq \varphi_2(x)\leq \dots$ for all $x\in X$ and $\varphi_n(x)\to \varphi(x)$ as $n\to \infty$ for all $x\in X$. So we can use the pointwise version of MCT and we obtain the following: $$\lim
_{n\to \infty}\int_{X}f_n(x)\chi_{X\setminus N} (x)d\mu=\int_{X}f(x)\chi_{X\setminus N} (x)d\mu.$$

Since each $f_n(x)$ is nonnegative on $X$ then using linearity and $\mu(N)=0$ we see that $\int_{X}f_n(x)\chi_{X\setminus N} (x)d\mu=\int_{X}f_n(x)d\mu$.

But we cannot use the same reasoning for the $\int_{X}f(x)\chi_{X\setminus N} (x)d\mu$ because $f(x)$ may not be non-negative on $X$. The only we know that $f(x)\geq 0$ a.e. on $X$. But linearity of Lebesgue integral is true  for nonnegative functions or integrable functions.

So my question is this:

If we assume that $f(x)\geq 0$ on $X$ then we are done. But what if we do not have this condition? Is it still true?

Can anyone explain it, please?

Comment: For any measurable function $f$, since $\mu(N) =0$, we have that $\int_{X}f(x)\chi_{ N} (x)d\mu= 0$. So, we have $\int_{X}f(x)\chi_{X\setminus N} (x)d\mu=\int_{X}f(x)d\mu$ (in the sense that if one integral exists so does the other and they are equal). If you want to prove this in all detail, you may want to decompose $f$ into $f^+$ and $f^-$.

Comment: @Ramiro, so by existence you mean that that integral is finite, right? I see what do you mean but my question is slightly different.

Comment: May we assume that it is know that: "For any measurable function $f$, since $\mu(N) =0$, we have that $\int_{X}f(x)\chi_{ N} (x)d\mu= 0$."?

Comment: No, by existence I mean it is defined, possibly infinite.

Comment: @Ramiro, yes. I do know that the Lebesgue integral of measurable function over set of zero measure is zero.

Comment: @Ramiro, could you show the proof of the above statement, please? I'd be happy to see it and I'll appreciate it!

Comment: I have posted a detailed answer, please let me know if you have any questions regarding the answer.

Comment: I have posted a second answer to your question. This second answer is more directly tied to your question. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding the answers.

Comment: I don't want to sound aggressive, but I think you have some serious deficiencies in Measure Theory. You clearly do not understand that the values of a function on a null set do not affect the value of its integral nor its integrability. You clearly believe that the assumption $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x \in X$. and the assumption $f(x)\geq 0$ a.e. in $X$ may produce different results in terms of the existence  or value of the integral of $f$.

Comment: @Ramiro, probably you are right. It is ok. I am learning measure may be for <2 months.

Comment: @Ramiro, Thanks a lot for your help! Take care.

Comment: Hi, I hope you are doing well. I have just come across this Wikipedia text and I thought it might interest you.  It is about, for signed functions, the definition of "existence of the integral" and the definition of "being Lebesgue integrable".  Please read **item 2.3.4** in this Wikipedia article. Here is the link: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration#Signed_functions

Comment: @Ramiro, Hi! Thanks a lot for your link. To be honest i cannot find item 2.3.4. What is the name of that item?

Comment: The link I sent opens directly on item 2.3.4.  The title of the item is "Signed functions". 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration#Signed_functions

Comment: @Ramiro, Sorry but can we discuss 1-2 questions related to this topic in chat, please? I'd be very thankful!

Comment: Yes, sure. It will be a pleasure. Now? Let me know when it will be a good time for you.

Comment: @Ramiro! Hi, I texted you. :)

Comment: I am in the chat already :)

Comment: I am in the chat. It seems we are missing each other.

Comment: Hi, Ramiro! If you are available could you join the chat, please?

Comment: Hi, ZFR.  How are you?  Would you like to chat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote:

> $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{X}f_n(x)\chi_{X\setminus N} (x)d\mu=\int_{X}f(x)\chi_{X\setminus N} (x)d\mu.$$
>
> Since each $f_n(x)$ is nonnegative on $X$ then using linearity and $\mu(N)=0$ we see that $\int_{X}f_n(x)\chi_{X\setminus N} (x)d\mu=\int_{X}f_n(x)d\mu$.
>
> But we cannot use the same reasoning for the $\int_{X}f(x)\chi_{X\setminus N} (x)d\mu$ because $f(x)$ may not be non-negative on $X$. The only we know that $f(x)\geq 0$ a.e. on $X$.

So, using linearity, you can conclude that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{X}f_n(x)(x)d\mu=\int_{X}f(x)\chi_{X\setminus N} (x)d\mu$$

Your question is how to deal with the right-hand size. Here is a simple solution:
Change the values of $f$ on a set of measure zero, to make it non-negative.

In detail:

Since $f(x)\geq 0$ a.e. on $X$, let us define the function $g$ by $g(x) = f(x)$ if $f(x) \geq 0$ and $g(x) = 0$ if $f(x) <0$.

Note that $g$ is non-negative, so $\int_X g(x) d\mu$ exists. Since $g$ is obtained from $f$ by just changing the values of $f$ on a set of measure zero, we have that  $\int_X f(x) d\mu$ exists and $\int_X f(x) d\mu= \int_X g(x) d\mu$.

Note also that $f\chi_{X\setminus N}= g\chi_{X\setminus N}$ a.e.. So you can take care of the right-hand side as follows, using the linearity for $g$.

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{X}f_n(x)(x)d\mu &=\int_{X}f(x)\chi_{X\setminus N} (x)d\mu \\
&=\int_{X}g(x)\chi_{X\setminus N} (x)d\mu \\
&=\int_{X}g(x) d\mu \\
&=\int_{X}f(x) d\mu 
\end{align*}

Comment: Since $g$ is non-negative then $\int_{X}g(x)d\mu \in [0,+\infty]$. If you claim that $\int_{X}f(x)d\mu$ exists we need to show that Lebesgue integrals of both $f^{\pm} (x)$ are finite. due to my definition of integrability. I hope that I was clear.

Comment: @ZFR  1. What part of "Since $g$ is obtained from $f$ by just changing the values of $f$ on a set of measure zero, we have that  $\int_X f(x) d\mu$ exists and $\int_X f(x) d\mu= \int_X g(x) d\mu$. " did you not understand? 


2.  Why you accept that $g$ may have an infinite integral, but does not accept that $f$ may have an infinite integral?  

3. Even if you require $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x \in X$, it does not ensure that $f$ will be integrable, it does not ensure that $f\in L(X)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that it is known that, for any measurable function $f$, if $N$ is a measurable set and  $\mu(N) =0$, then $\int_{X}f(x)\chi_{ N} (x)d\mu= 0$. Let us prove the following result.

> For any measurable function $f$, if $N$ is a measurable set and  $\mu(N) =0$, then:
>
> 1. $\int_{X}f(x)d\mu$ exists if and only if $\int_{X}f(x)\chi_{X\setminus N} (x)d\mu$ exists.
> 2. Moreover, if one of those integrals exists (and so both exist), then $\int_{X}f(x)d\mu =\int_{X}f(x)\chi_{X\setminus N} (x)d\mu$.

Now, given any measurable function $f$, consider  its positive part $f^+$ and its negative part $f^-$.  Both $f^+$ and $f^-$ are positive measurable functions. So we have

\begin{align*} 
\int_{X}f^+(x)d\mu &= \int_{X}f^+(x)\chi_{X\setminus N} (x)d\mu +\int_{X}f^+(x)\chi_{ N} (x)d\mu\\
&= \int_{X}f^+(x)\chi_{X\setminus N} (x)d\mu + 0\\
& =  \int_{X}(f\chi_{X\setminus N})^+ (x)d\mu
\end{align*}
and

\begin{align*} 
\int_{X}f^-(x)d\mu &= \int_{X}f^-(x)\chi_{X\setminus N} (x)d\mu +\int_{X}f^-(x)\chi_{ N} (x)d\mu \\ 
&= \int_{X}f^-(x)\chi_{X\setminus N} (x)d\mu + 0\\ 
&=  \int_{X}(f\chi_{X\setminus N})^- (x)d\mu
\end{align*}

Now, the integral of $f$ on $X$ exists (is defined) if and only if $ \int_{X}f^+(x)d\mu <+\infty$  **or** $\int_{X}f^-(x)d\mu< +\infty$  which is equivalent to say that $ \int_{X}(f\chi_{X\setminus N})^+ (x)d\mu+\infty$  **or** $\int_{X}(f\chi_{X\setminus N})^- (x)d\mu< +\infty$ which is equivalent to say that the integral of $f\chi_{X\setminus N}$ on $X$ exists (is defined).

Morever, if the  integral of $f$ on $X$ exists (and equivalenty, the integral of $f\chi_{X\setminus N}$ on $X$ exists), we have

\begin{align*} 
\int_{X}f(x)d\mu &= \int_{X}f^+(x)d\mu-\int_{X}f^-(x)d\mu \\
&=\int_{X}(f\chi_{X\setminus N})^+ (x)d\mu - \int_{X}(f\chi_{X\setminus N})^- (x)d\mu \\
&=\int_{X}(f\chi_{X\setminus N}) (x)d\mu \\
&=\int_{X}f(x)\chi_{X\setminus N} (x)d\mu 
\end{align*}

So, we have proved that, for any measurable function $f$, if $N$ is a measurable set and  $\mu(N) =0$, then $\int_{X}f(x)d\mu$ exists if and only if $\int_{X}f(x)\chi_{X\setminus N} (x)d\mu$ exists. Moreover, if one of those integrals exists (and so both exist), then $\int_{X}f(x)d\mu =\int_{X}f(x)\chi_{X\setminus N} (x)d\mu$.

**Remark 1**: There are TWO definitions that are related but different. One definition regards the existence of the integral (which can be infinite) of measurable functions. This definition requires that just   $f^-$ **or** $f^+$ has finite integral.The second definition is the definition of $f$ being  Lebesgue integrable, which requires that both $f^-$ **and** $f^+$ have finite integrals.

The first definition is more general and the measurable functions that satisfy it are sometimes called "semi-integrable". Of course, if $f$ is integrable (second definition) it is automatically semi-integrable (first definition).

Note that the Monotone Convergence Theorem applies to the more general class of semi-integrable functions, in the sense that it does not require (nor conclude) that the functions have finite integral. The functions $f_n$ or $f$ may have infinite integrals. No assumption is made that $f_n$ or $f$ are integrable.

Accordingly, the result I have proved above is also for class of semi-integrable functions.

**Remark 2**: In the question $f(x) \geqslant 0$ a. e.  It means that there is $N$ measurable  such that $\mu(N)=0$ and $f(x) \geqslant 0$ for all $x\in X\setminus N$. In particular, $f(x)\chi_{X\setminus N} (x)  \geqslant 0$, for all $x\in X$ and
we have that $\int_{X}f(x)\chi_{X\setminus N} (x)d\mu$ exists.

In my answer, I prove that $\int_{X}f(x)d\mu$ exists if and only if $\int_{X}f(x)\chi_{X\setminus N} (x)d\mu$ exists. Moreover, if one of those integrals exists (and so both exist), then $\int_{X}f(x)d\mu =\int_{X}f(x)\chi_{X\setminus N} (x)d\mu$.

So, in the case of the question, from the fact  that $\int_{X}f(x)\chi_{X\setminus N} (x)d\mu$ exists we conclude that $\int_{X}f(x)d\mu$ exists and that $\int_{X}f(x)d\mu =\int_{X}f(x)\chi_{X\setminus N} (x)d\mu$.

Comment: I see that my definition of Lebesgue integrable function is a bit different than yours. I say that $f(x)\in L(X)$ (means that $f(x)$ is Lebesgue integrable on $X$) iff $f^+(x)\in L(X)$ and $f^-(x)\in L(X)$.

Comment: @ZFR  No. It seems you are confusing two concepts. I added a "Remark" at the end of my answer. I hope it clarifies the point.

Comment: @ZFR Please, let me know if you have any further question.

Comment: Actually i do have a question. I am trying to formulate it rigorously. I will write it very soon.

Comment: @ZFR I added one more paragraph at the end of the proof (before the remarrk). I hope it helps.

Comment: I read your proof carefully and I got it. But I cannot get the connection with my question. The problem that in my question $f(x)$ may not be nonnegative. It is actually $f(x)\geq 0$ a.e. on $X$ and you cannot claim that $\int_X f(x)d\mu$ exists.

Comment: So my opinion is that even in $\mu$-a.e. version of MCT theorem we have to assume that $f(x)\geq 0$ for each $x\in X$.

Comment: @ZFR Remember that, if $f \ge 0$ a.e., then $f^{-}=0$ a.e. Therefore $\int f^{-}=0$, and $\int f$ is well-defined (possibly is infinite).

Comment: @ZFR    $1$. I have added a second remark (Remark 2) to explain in detail how my answer answers your question. 

$2$. If $f(x)\geqslant0$ a.e. on $X$, I can claim that $\int_Xf(x)d\mu$ exists. Please, see my Remark 2 for details.

Comment: @ZFR Please, re-read Remark 1 and note that to ensure that $\int_X f(x) d\mu$ exists, it is enough to ensure that $\int_X f^-(x) d\mu$  **or** $\int_X f^+(x) d\mu$  is finite. If $f(x)\geqslant 0$ a.e., then $f^-(x) =0$ a.e. and we have  $\int_X f^-(x) d\mu=0$ and so  $\int_X f^-(x) d\mu$ is finite. So, $\int_X f(x) d\mu$ exists. 

In fact, if a measurable function $f$  is non-negative a.e. then $\int_X f(x) d\mu$ exists and $\int_X f(x) d\mu =\int_X f^+(x) d\mu $.

Comment: @ZFR Have you read Remark 2?  Is it now clear for you how my answer answrs your question?

Comment: Dear Ramiro! Thanks a lot for such a great help! I read all your answers very carefully. I understand them. But the problem that we are misunderstanding each other. My definition of Lebesgue integrability is slightly different than yours. As I said before I claim that $f\in L(X)$ iff $f^{\pm}(x)\in L(X)$ (and BOTH those values be FINITE). So in my case it is better to assume that $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in X$ in order not to contradict to my definition of integrability.

Comment: @ZFR 1. The MCT is not about integrable functions. It works even when the the integrals goes to infinity. 

2. Assuming $f(x) \geq 0$ a.e.  does not contradict the definition of integralibiliy, because in this case $f^-=0$ a.e.,  so $f^-0 \in L(X)$ and you have that $f$ will be in $L(X)$ if and only if $f^+$  is in $L(X)$. 

A function being negative on a set of measure zero does not prevent it from being integrable.